# How to delay python code without blocking other processes

Tags: python-3.x, time, synchronous

I want to delay my python code execution but not blocking means I don't want to stop whole code while that process is running.

My code for a telegram bot:

```
from time import sleep
from . import dispatcher
from telegram import Update, CommandHandler, CallbackContext 

def start(update, context):
    update.effective_message.reply_text("Hello")
    sleep(3)
    update.effective_message.reply_text("end")

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start, pass_args=True, run_async=True))
```

In the code above everything works fine but i can't run other codes while this works

any solution for this?

I don't want to use asynchronous
want with synchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a thread and use the condition object.
You can create a condition object and use its wait() method. It also has an optional timeout argument.

Refer:

[Condition Object](https://web.archive.org/web/20200319103023/http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm)

[wait() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.wait)